# How do I give permission for ChromiumWebBrowser to access my microphone for speech input in c# WinForm

Tags: sunone

If I browse to Google's home page with Chrome, I can click the microphone icon and I'll be prompted with a dialog to allow access to the mic. If I agree, I can speak my search request.

If I do this with CefSharp's ChromiumWebBrowser, I can click the icon, but I'm never prompted to give my permission.

Is there a handler I need to implement to do this, or is it something that still needs to be implemented?